# matplotlib scatter plot add legend without loop and without using seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, legend, python-3.8

I receive the error `No handles with labels found to put in legend.` when running the code below. How can I add a legend to this scatter plot that shows the color definitions (a red dot for A, blue dot for B, green dot for C)?

```
### Dummy Dataset
x = [0,1,-1,4,0,2,2,4,2]
y = [1,5,9,2,4,2,5,6,1]
cat = ['A','B','B','B','A','C','A','B','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y,cat)), columns =['x', 'y', 'cat'])

### Build color definitions
df.loc[:, 'color'] = df.cat
df.color.replace(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['red', 'blue', 'green'], inplace=True)
display(df)

### Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax1.scatter(df.x, df.y, edgecolors = 'none', c = df.color)
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', facecolor='white', frameon=1, 
           framealpha=1, labelspacing=0.2, borderpad=0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: you did specify the labels for the scatter plot, as the warning says

Comment: @PaulH yes the question is how to do that?

Comment: simplest version is add the `label` kwarg to your call to `scatter`. If not all, nearly all matplotlib plotting functions take `label` as a parameter according to their docstrings, which you can see in jupyter by executing e.g., `ax1.scatter?`. For more advanced legends, the second scatter example in the matplotlib documentation is pretty exhaustive https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automated-legend-creation

Comment: Should have said this in the OP, but I also tried `myplot = ax1.scatter(df...` and `ax1.legend(*myplot.legend_elements(), loc='upper...`), which returned the error `UserWarning: Collection without array used. Make sure to specify the values to be colormapped via the `c` argument.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might not be a way to do this without a simple loop. Based on the procedure [here](https://kanoki.org/2020/08/30/matplotlib-scatter-plot-color-by-category-in-python/), the following code works.

```
x = [0,1,-1,4,0,2,2,4,2]
y = [1,5,9,2,4,2,5,6,1]
cat = ['A','B','B','B','A','C','A','B','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x,y,cat)), columns =['x', 'y', 'cat'])

mycolorsdict = {'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'green'}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
grouped = df.groupby('cat')
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax1, kind='scatter', 
               x='x', y='y', 
               label=key, color=mycolorsdict[key])
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', facecolor='white', frameon=1, 
           framealpha=1, labelspacing=0.2, borderpad=0.25)
```

[image]